# How to paste code into vim without super indenting issue

Tags: command-line, vim, vi

I paste into the gedit text editor and that'
s ok (on the left).

But when I paste into vim (on the right) i get the weird 'too much indenting' issue.  Also it's not immediately fixable with selecting all text and using `=`

This for python code btw, i will check ruby now - done, ruby doesn't have issue, but then again ruby outdents with ends anyway so different approach in that language anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open up vim type the following

:set paste

and when before you exit

```
:set nopaste
```

You might also check the top answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861627/paste-in-insert-mode) post